# Alter folder permission in windows command line?

Tags: windows, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to grant permission to users for a directory using command line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows)

I want to grant all users of a system the permissions of read, write and modify for a folder.
I think there would be a command line that I use to do that, but if there is nothing and I have to write a code for it please help me with it.

Main Problem is that I want to grant these permissions to all users, usually I don't care about UserNames and I want to put "*" instead of usernames, to apply new permissions for all users.

any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: It's confusing that this is tagged c# and cmd. Do you want advice on creating a C# program that changes permissions?

Comment: Sure, that would be works! I tagged C# to show that I can code sth in C#.

Comment: The tag should describe the question and not you :-) So you should tag c# only if the question is about c#.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There **is** a command line - [CACLS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx).

For example, to add "Everyone" with "Full Control" to the folder `c:\temp\test` you would use:

```
REM /t means "apply change recursively"
REM /e means "edit existing DACL". 
REM     Omitting this will overwrite the existing DACL.
cacls c:\temp\Test /t /e /g Everyone:f
```

Comment: By everyone here you mean every user in every domain that uses this computer?

Comment: `Everyone` is a built-in group in Windows. See http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-security_groups.html for a list. You can also use CACLS to set permissions for individual users, using (for example) ` /g MyDomain\RB:f` to give me FullControl.

Comment: Giving everyone modify permission means anyone can delete the folder... anyone... any software... any virus... anyone! Generally, if you're on a Windows Domain, it's better to use the built in group 'Authenticated Users' which is everyone logged in.

Comment: On any halfway recent Windows I'd recommend using [`icacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) instead of `cacls`. Unlike the latter the former will also handle inheritance.

Comment: i was looking for recursive. I used /T /C successfully. Thanks.