# Physical Path in Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm totally newbie in Beanstalk. I'm developing a web application in which a sealed and black-box plugin is used. That plugin needs a physical path with full permission to use for cache.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the .ebextensions files in the main project that will, for example, create a directory and change the access rights to it. It is not clear from your question how you install the plugin (e.g. is it a service that is loaded after the web application is installed or is it part of the web application).

Execute a command in the .ebextensions file such as in:

[How to grant permission to users for a directory using command line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows)

You'll find a introduction into container customization in

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html

Be careful about the format of the files (ie. spaces, no tabs, the best is to edit it in a separate text editor). Experiment with simple commands first, so that you get the hang of how the commands are executed.

Note: The ebextensions commands are executed for each deployment, so your script should check if the directory exists already and only create it if it doesn't. Otherwise the execution will fail as you try to create a directory that exists already. In a second step you can add the permissions.