# Error upon opening project in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Error:Failed to create parent directory

> 'C:\Users\fredmar.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.sonatype.oss\oss-parent\9'
>   when creating directory
>   'C:\Users\fredmar.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.sonatype.oss\oss-parent\9\e5cdc4d23b86d79c436f16fed20853284e868f65'

Answer (score 0):

You have not given much info about your environment. Are you running first time? Did you open the studio as Administrator?

What version of wndows you're using? what version gradle you are using?

Do you have permission to `C:\Users\fredmar.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.sonatype.oss\oss-parent\9`  folder?

Try give permission to the user. if you are not sure follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows)

Comment: This is not the first time I'm using android studio, but one day i opened it this error appears, im using windows 8, gradle 1.5 and i opened as Administrator