# PostgreSQL: export data to csv file

Tags: postgresql, csv

I want to export the data in a table of some PostgreSQL database to a csv file.
Since the standard copy command does not work, I tried the following:

```
\copy (SELECT * FROM persons) to 'C:\tmp\persons_client.csv' with csv
```

just as in 
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/export-postgresql-table-to-csv-file/ .
The path seems to be correct; however, I get the error message

```
FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei »\«
LINE 1: \copy [...]
```

which means that there is a syntax error at the "\" sign before the copy statement.
Any ideas what I missed?

By the way, this is not the real problem I'm currently facing. 
Actually I was trying to import a csv file but unfortunately I do not seem to have sufficient privileges and when just using "COPY", the permission will be denied. so I tried to import the file using "\copy" but still get the same error message I get when trying to export using "\copy".

Comment: you have to run it in `psql` - it is this specific client metacommand, not an sql one

Comment: Do I have to? I'm using pgAdmin 4. If I nevertheless have to run it in psql, what exactly would I have to change?

Comment: `psql -c "\copy (SELECT * FROM persons) to 'C:\tmp\persons_client.csv' with csv" should perfectly work, and pgadmin has its own save to csv functionality somewhere

Comment: The thing is that for future purposes, I will have to automatically import/export a ton of files which would be infeasible to be done manually^^

Comment: another argument to use psql, not pgadmin for you

Comment: I've tried

`psql -c "\copy (SELECT * FROM persons) to 'C:\tmp\persons_client.csv' with csv`


which yields the error

FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei »psql« (syntax error at psql)

Answer (score 0):

`\copy (SELECT * FROM persons) to 'C:\tmp\persons_client.csv' with csv` would not work in pgAdmin, because `\copy` is an [pslq metacommand](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

> Performs a frontend (client) copy. This is an operation that runs an
>   SQL COPY command, but instead of the server reading or writing the
>   specified file, psql reads or writes the file and routes the data
>   between the server and the local file system. This means that file
>   accessibility and privileges are those of the local user, not the
>   server, and no SQL superuser privileges are required.

Comment: Anything I can do to achieve my goal using pgAdmin?

Comment: https://www.question-defense.com/2010/10/15/how-to-export-from-pgadmin-export-pgadmin-data-to-csv and please ask one question at a time. please don't use comments for on line help line

Comment: well, this doesn't exactly help me. I already figured out how to export tables to csv manually. but I want to do more than one at a time...

Comment: just another reason to move to psql from pgadmin. you can sit on two cheers - pgadmin friendly to query by hand, psql easily cronned

Answer (score 0):

Issue this command on `PgAdmin` or `psql`:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM persons) to 'C:\\tmp\\persons_client.csv' with csv;
```

Don't forget to escape Windows file separator.

Comment: "error, couldn't open file 'persons_client.csv' for writing" ... :-(

Comment: You must ensure that your path exists (`tmp` folder in your case) and is writable.

Comment: @frau_tana Please see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8311008).

Comment: Another important point: Your server is remote? If yes, you'll cannot do COPY this way because it will attempt to access `C:\\tmp\\persons_client.csv` on server. In this case you must use `stdout` to write to local file.

Answer (score 0):

```
\COPY (SELECT * FROM persons) to 'persons_client.csv' with csv;
```

Comment: Please briefly explain your answer