# How to set file/folder permission for azure cloud service package

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

I'm using VSTS to deploy a azure cloud service package and getting a file access issue for web.config not able to be written to after a successful deployment.

At the moment I manually set the file permission via RDP to correct it for eg. on e:\siteroot\1\Web.config (Everyone FC)

To avoid this manual step - how can I set a folder/file permission for a file under cloud service deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems not related to azure projects directly. It's not suggest to give a permission with Everyone FC, this may cause security risk.

For Azure Cloud Services Web Roles, the default Application Pool Identity account is “**Network Service**”.

In a normal basis the Application Pool account needs **read** permission over the web.config file so it can read all the application configuration. 
[image]

For this kind of issue, you could creating a Startup Task to give write permission to Network Service in the application Web.config file.

Please go through the detail steps in this similar issue: [Error “Access to the path ‘E:sitesrootWeb.config’ is denied” when storing Azure AD’s public key in Web.config of an Azure Cloud Services application.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2016/01/15/error-access-to-the-path-esitesroot0web-config-is-denied-when-storing-azure-ads-public-key-in-web-config-of-an-azure-cloud-services-application/)

Also take a look at this related question: [Web.config Access denied when Package Azure cloud services projects in Visual Studio 2013 for Web](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4de8bf44-2ed3-45ef-af22-cb5f2b01974c/webconfig-access-denied-when-package-azure-cloud-services-projects-in-visual-studio-2013-for-web?forum=windowsazuredevelopment)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .bat file where you call the `icacls` command with the parameters you prefer:

[How to grant permission to users for a directory using command line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows)

and then you can configure a startup task for your cloud service to run this file:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-startup-tasks