# Set folder permissions to `IIS_IUSRS` group in Inno Setup

Tags: iis, inno-setup, acl

My web application is accessing some folders outside of `wwwroot` and thus needs access to them. The web application is installed via Inno Setup. How can I use Inno Setup's folder permissions to grant access to the `IIS_IUSRS` group?

https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers the SID of `IIS_IUSRS` is `S-1-5-32-568`.

Comment: If I were you, I would have all installation steps wrapped in a PowerShell script and then call it from Inno Setup events. That saves you from converting everything to Pascal script and external calls to different command line tools.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot grant access to an ad-hoc group with Inno Setup directly. You have to use an external tool, like [`icacls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls).

Something like this (untested):

```
[Run]
Filename: "icacls"; Parameters: """C:\path"" /grant: IIS_IUSRS:rw"; Flags: runhidden
```

Also see

- [Adding IIS_IUSRS with write permission to a directory programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51200319/850848)
- [How to give one specific user rights to a folder in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54147843/850848)

Answer (score -1):

You can follow below steps:

1)Get the folder path where you want to assign permission

2)In the `[Dirs]` section of your Inno Setup script, add an entry for each directory you need to modify permissions for.

3)Use the `Permissions` parameter to grant the necessary permissions. you want to grant permissions to the `IIS_IUSRS` group. Since you have the SID (Security Identifier) for `IIS_IUSRS`, which is `S-1-5-32-568`, you can use it directly.

Below is the sample code:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\YourFolder"; Permissions: "S-1-5-32-568:full"
```

4)After making these changes, compile your Inno Setup script and test the installer to ensure that the permissions are correctly applied.

Comment: This won't work. It won't even compile. 1) The syntax is `id-access`, not `id:access` 2) the `id` cannot be SID (and the mere fact that the separator is `-`, shows that you cannot use any kind of `id` with dashes).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl You're correct that the syntax used in Inno Setup for folder permissions does not directly accept SIDs and the separator should indeed be a slash instead of a colon. Inno Setup uses a predefined set of constants for setting permissions in the [Dirs] section, such as users, admins, everyone, etc.Unfortunately, Inno Setup does not natively support setting permissions for SIDs like IIS_IUSRS directly in the script.

Comment: you could try this as well: `[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\MyFolder"; 

[Run]
Filename: "icacls"; Parameters: """{app}\MyFolder"" /grant *S-1-5-32-568:(OI)(CI)F"; Flags: runhidden`

Comment: IIRC, you must prefix SIDs in the icacls command line with `*` (as in your comment).