# Django media not loading, static files working

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a jango site, static files are working, media is not loaded from the media folder, if the picture in static files is visible. The folder is listed correctly, pycharm gives a fall in the folder

setings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
import debug_toolbar

# Server statics and uploaded media
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
# Allow error pages to be tested
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^403$', handler403),
    url(r'^404$', handler404),
    url(r'^500$', handler500),
    url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),

]
```

I use django oscar, this can be the cause of the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows you can refer this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, you should executed pycharm with run as administrator or apache service executed run as administartor ,or Enter the absolute path to the media file like:
"C:\Users\dr_r00t3r\DjangoProject\media"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the access to the desired folder is not possible. To do this, you must run the following command:

```
chown -R $user:www-data /home/media/
or
chmod 755 -r /home/media
```

Comment: how to use in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if I use full path to media, it's working.
like this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'F:/Work/Mebli1/backup-7.30.2018_21-56-35_u6487/homedir/furniture/furniture/home/media'
```