# Static files won't load

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-staticfiles

I`ve created a new Django project and ran into a problem with static images. So, apparently when i was connecting my css and javascript files with static it worked well, but when i tried to connect images they won't load.
here is my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_DIRS = ['static']

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from store import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mstore.urls')),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

here is example of how i display it in template

```
<a href="#" class="item__image">
<picture><source srcset="img/collections/featured/02.webp" type="image/webp">
<img src="{% static 'mstore/img/collections/featured/02.png' %}" alt="Lore Walnut"></picture></a>
```

Please, before answering note that i checked the src of the image in browser, and it worked.

[image: src of image in browser]
i copied this link and pasted in browser and got this
[image]
Besides, css and js works great, so i think the problem is in images

I tried to run python manage.py collectstatic and it worked perfectly.

Comment: check your static directory permission.
This is a duplicate question.
check this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690071/django-media-not-loading-static-files-working

Comment: What is static directory permission? i cant understand what to do, i changed static path to absolute, run pycharm as administrator but still no changes

Comment: In urlpatterns you need another static() pattern with STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL. CSS and JS are most likely cached and without browser cache would break as well.

Comment: Your `srcset` has an URL that is _not_ `{% static %}`'d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just forgot to static my srcsets and it caused the problem.