# Does the chmod command not work on Windows in GitBash?

Tags: git-bash

I'm working on simulating some commands in a Unix-like environment. I'm on Windows 10 and using GitBash's shell to run commands but chmod doesn't appear to keep the permission changes on a file.

```
zecuse MINGW64 ~ (dev)
$ touch test
zecuse MINGW64 ~ (dev)
$ ls -l test
-rw-r--r-- 1 zecuse 1049089 0 Nov 13 13:30 test
zecuse MINGW64 ~ (dev)
$ chmod -c -r test
mode of 'test' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0200 (-w-------)
zecuse MINGW64 ~ (dev)
$ ls -l test
-rw-r--r-- 1 zecuse 1049089 0 Nov 13 13:30 test
```

Does Windows prevent me from changing file permissions in this way? If so, do I need to use powershell to modify a file's permissions?

Comment: [An off-SO solution](https://chaosandpenguins.com/2016/10/25/chmod-is-ignored-in-the-git-bash-prompt/) that worked in my case: Add a `#!/bin/bash` line. Though I still find it odd that chmod doesn't work from Git Bash. Am I too used to Cygwin? Why have I never noticed this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalent of `chmod` would be `icacls`

Please refer -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls

[How to grant permission to users for a directory using command line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows)

In case of `chmod 0200` - user write permission

Try using cmd `prompt` or PowerShell

> icacls test1 /grant User1:(w)

Comment: Is this run in powershell? When run in gitbash `icacls test3 /grant zecuse:\(N\)` I'm getting `Invalid parameter "C:/Program Files/Git/grant"`.

Comment: Yes. This should be run in powershell

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't seem like the windows file system is compatible with gitbash chmod:  https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/dss843/chmod_not_working_with_git_bash_in_windows/

I don't think this is relevant to powershell.