# Is it possible to make a script executable in git bash?

Tags: git, shell, github, git-bash

Whenever I write a script, and I try to make it executable using  `chmod u+x` it never does anything, and I can never commit the change, but when I run the same command in another terminal, it works

I tried running the `chmod u+x` and I expected to be able to commit the changes but it said there were no changes to commit

Comment: Did you try [`git update-index --chmod=+x`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21694391/10871900) maybe (in case git bash uses git attributes)? Alternatively, what's the result of `ls -la`?

Comment: Seems like an old well-know problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36401322/7976758 "*Note: `chmod +x` does **nothing** to a script's executability on Git Bash. It won't hurt to run it, but it won't accomplish anything either.*" https://stackoverflow.com/a/58946520/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-bash%5D+chmod