# I have a setup.exe created using .net and Visual Studio, I want to change the permission of the default folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio, setup-project

I have a setup.exe created using .net and Visual Studio, I want to change the permission of the default folder where the setup.exe is installing the application.

Will I have to make changes in vdproj file?? if yes can anyone please help me where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change permission to Administrator to be able to change folder permissions. Furthermore, changing the permissions of that directory requires a file located outside of the directory containing your setup.exe file to make changes to the default directory permissions.

One solution is that you can use CMD commands with Administrator privileges to change your default directory permissions after your program installs.

You need to know the directory path after your setup.exe is installed.

See this article for how to use CMD to change default directory permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311008/12772355