# python write string to file gives empty file

Tags: python

I try to write a string to a file in Python and fail,

```
mystr = '{"a": "{\'a\': [\'b\': [\'\\saaaalam\\Mira.h\']}, {\'c\': [\'C:\\a\\t.exe\']}", "b": "open"}'

with open('test.json', 'w') as out_file:
   out_file.write(mystr)
```

The file "test.json" does not exist! However, if I for example remove an "a" in "saaalam" it works.

Comment: your code works good for me. can you paste the error

Comment: For me It worked just fine, I don't know if your json format is good but it saved for me the json file and the text in it as well

Comment: Here is a cleaner way to define your variable: `mystr = r'''{"a": "{'a': ['b': ['\saaaalam\Mira.h']}, {'c': ['C:\a\t.exe']}", "b": "open"}'''`. It is easier to read without all those ```\'```.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. As I wrote, if I just change a single character, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working. You should check if python process has the right to create that file in your OS. In Linux and MacOS you can provide yourself access to write in the current directory with:

```sh
chmod 744 .
```

Another option is you are looking for your file at the wrong place. You should check the working directory in your IDE or try to run the script from the console.

Comment: Judging by the drive letter in the string and all that backslashes, I guess the OP is on Windows and then `chmod` is not an option.

Comment: Maybe so, I hadn't thought that content of variable could mean something :) Then I'll just left [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows) here.